# Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.9: Yum Updates Not Working: TypeError 'NoneType'

Tags: download, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

We have a RHEL 5.9 which is refusing to apply updates. For example, if I do a command like: yum update then I get an error like in this thread: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=824663 [I don't want to waste any space here by copying/pasting the whole error]. Basically, the error says:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I have not found a solution yet. I have asked someone in our IT team to check the server's registration with Redhat but it may take a long time to get an answer and I need to have this resolved now.

Per some online solutions I have tried commenting out line 226/227 from the /**init**.py file but then I get a warning from Redhat about some kind of violation.

Now, my immediate needs are to download some RPMs from yum.postgresql.org and so Redhat doesn't need to be involved right now.

How can I go around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind-- our IT staff had to re-register the server with the Redhat Network (RHN). Problem fixed!
Thanks.